# How in the spring of custom import ftl, as spring.ftl

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My package `com.caobug.client.support.view` have paging macro `pagination.ftl` and `FreeMarkerConfigurer.java`

**FreeMarkerConfigurer.java:**

```
public class FreeMarkerConfigurer extends org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer {
    @Override
    protected void postProcessTemplateLoaders(List<TemplateLoader> templateLoaders) {
        super.postProcessTemplateLoaders(templateLoaders);
        templateLoaders.add(new ClassTemplateLoader(FreeMarkerConfigurer.class, ""));
    }
}
```

spring-views.xml:

```
<bean id="freeMarkerConfigurer" class="com.caobug.client.support.view.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf-8"/>
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
    <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="template_update_delay">10</prop>
            <prop key="locale">zh_CN</prop>
            <prop key="number_format">0.####</prop>
            <prop key="datetime_format">yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</prop>
            <prop key="classic_compatible">true</prop>
            <prop key="template_exception_handler">ignore</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="freemarkerVariables">
        <map>
            <entry key="shiro">
                <bean class="com.caobug.tags.account.ShiroTags"/>
            </entry>
            <entry key="messageTotal">
                <bean class="com.caobug.tags.account.MessageCountTag"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

demo.ftl:

```
<#import "/pagination.ftl" as pagination />
```

### Get the following error:

```
==> #import "/pagination.ftl" as pagination  [in template "demo.ftl" at line 1, column 1]
----------
```

What can I do?

Comment: What is the rest of the exception?

Comment: FreeMarker template error:
Error reading imported template /pagination.ftl

The failing instruction (FTL stack trace):
----------
==> #import "/pagination.ftl" as pagination  [in template "demo.ftl" at line 1, column 1]
----------

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----------
freemarker.core._MiscTemplateException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]....Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "/pagination.ftl" not found.

Comment: From the exception message, it seems that the file `pagination.ftl` was not found.  Is this file located at `/WEB-INF/pagination.ftl`?

Comment: No spring.ftl under WEB-INF, why can be found? For example, <#import "/spring.ftl" as spring />

Comment: `spring.ftl` is a special case. It is loaded from the Spring Web MVC or Spring Web MVC Support JAR. It is in the same package (folder) as the class `FreeMarkerViewResolver` which loads it, which is the reason why the `/` at the beginning of the import declaration works. Imports for FTL files created within the app must follow relative paths. For example, if both `home.ftl` and `pagination.ftl` are in `WEB-INF`, you can use `#import "/pagination.ftl` in `home.ftl`. If however `pagination.ftl` is in `WEB-INF/common`, you need to use `#import "/common/pagination.ftl` in `home.ftl` and so on.